# pyglet - weird gray border on image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm writing a simple game in pyglet (python 3). I have [this cloud sprite.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4pNs.png)

However, when I blit it, it looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlqtB.png)

The gray border obviously isn't intended, so I'm wondering how to fix it.

This is what I'm using to enable blitting an image with alpha:

```
from pyglet import gl    

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would need to see where and how you actually draw/blit the image. Just the relevant part of how you load the image and how you draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using regular `resource` objects and you're blitting them one by one using `image.blit(X, Y)`.
This works, but requires a lot of more work and I think processing time as well as you have to set and reset alpha channels for each image you blit.

However, if you use sprites alpha channels becomes a automated feature and you don't have to worry to much about it.

This solves the problem, and is also a speed enhancer in the long run:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.clock
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()
window.config.alpha_size = 8

bg = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('bg.png'))
cloud = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('cloud.png'))

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    bg.draw()
    cloud.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: @twentyseven You're welcome. If you want to move around the cloud, just do `cloud.x += 10` for instance. Best of luck!